# Slider not showing on Magento Theme 'Minimo' by Modulesgarden

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, slider

I'm currently working with a magento website on localhost, version 1.9.3.1 and I've just installed the theme in the title but I can't get the built in slider to show on the homepage.

Has anyone ever used this theme or if not, be willing to download it and help me resolve my issue?

I know normally themes come with some code you have to paste into the homepage to get various features etc to show but from what I can this has come with none and I think the issue lies there somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: post your code for reference otherwise because question is related to third party theme

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any code. Like I said in my question, themes normally come with some guidance on how to turn on certain features etc but this has none, so I'm not sure where to start to get the slider to activate.

Comment: in code you will find module for slider. You have to find the code that not working for you.

Comment: I found this , is there some other file I can look for?
http://paste.ofcode.org/3LsfXUmeM6niJfnxpAE73L